# Using Apache Velocity with Spring Framework 3.2.4

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, apache, velocity

I'm new to Spring and I wanted to set it up using Velocity. Therefore I created in Eclipse Kepler with the Spring Tool Suite Extension a new Spring Project, a new Spring MVC Project. Then I added `org.apache.velocity` to the new Spring Project with the version 1.7. After that I added the following lines to my `servlet-context.xml`, according to http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/velocity/VelocityConfigurer.html

```
<beans:bean id="velocityConfig"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer">
    <beans:property name="resourceLoaderPath" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- View resolvers can also be configured with ResourceBundles or XML files. 
    If you need different view resolving based on Locale, you have to use the 
    resource bundle resolver. -->
<beans:bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="cache" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>
```

Then everything is fine. But if I change the Version of the Springframework in the pom.xml from 3.1.1.RELEASE to 3.2.4.RELEASE, I get the following error shown in Eclipse:

```
No setter found for property 'resourceLoaderPath' in class 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer'
```

I have even setted up a new Virtual Machine with Ubuntu to test it - I get the same error everywhere. Do you need any more files from me?

The output of mvn dependency:tree doesn't looks suspicious in my opinion, does it?

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building test 1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ c ---
[INFO] a.b:c:war:1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.6.10:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.6:runtime
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.6:runtime
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.15:runtime
[INFO] +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet.jsp:jsp-api:jar:2.1:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.7:test
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.9.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] \- org.apache.velocity:velocity:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO]    +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO]    \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.764s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Nov 03 14:15:18 CET 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/149M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And if I run the project on a Tomcat Server, I get the following error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet threw exception

type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer] for bean with name 'velocityConfig' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/ui/velocity/VelocityEngineFactory
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer] for bean with name 'velocityConfig' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/ui/velocity/VelocityEngineFactory
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1482)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.velocity.VelocityConfigurer] for bean with name 'velocityConfig' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]: problem with class file or dependent class; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/ui/velocity/VelocityEngineFactory
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1278)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1344)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:355)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:334)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:321)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeanNamesForType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1174)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:102)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:163)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/ui/velocity/VelocityEngineFactory
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2918)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1174)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1669)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:260)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:416)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1296)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1267)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1344)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:355)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:334)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:321)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeanNamesForType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1174)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:102)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:163)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactory
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:2918)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1174)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1669)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:260)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:416)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1296)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1267)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:575)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1344)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:355)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:334)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:321)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeanNamesForType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1174)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:102)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:163)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:628)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.47 logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
```

Comment: A couple of tips. Try running "mvn" outside eclipse to see if it is a dependency issue or eclipse. Also, run "mvn dependency:tree" from the command line and inspect the versions of dependencies getting pulled in.

Comment: I've added the output to my question - it looks alright to me…because i can run it on a tomcat server i don't think it is an eclipse issue?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is now clearly a classpath issue.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/ui/velocity/VelocityEngineFactory
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactory
```

You are missing the `spring-context-support` jar which contains the `VelocityEngineFactory` class.

Add this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks, thanks, thanks! You don't know how happy I'm now and how much time I have spent on trying to solve this issue by my own. You are awesome!!!

Comment: @Paloran Here's a trick, if you don't know it already, in Eclipse, press `CTRL + SHIFT + T` and write the name of the class. If it doesn't find it, then it's missing from your project's classpath. If it does find it, in the Project Explorer, you can click the `Link with Editor` arrows button to see which jar it's actually in.